# Detect tap on empty area in List

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, detect, empty-list

How can I detect a tap on empty area in `List` ? I tried using `List.onTapGesture {}` which kind of works but it overrides the tap on the rows. I only want it to trigger for the empty area not occupied by rows.

Comment: There is no such view as "empty space view" to assign a gesture to it. It is `UITableView` itself - area not covered with `UITableViewCell` views. Yes, they are still there.

Comment: @Asperi thanks, can you think of another way of solving my problem?

Comment: Check out the beta version of `collectionView(_:contextMenuConfigurationForItemsAt:point:)` [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/4002186-collectionview), specifically, `An empty array indicates that a person is invoking the menu from a location that doesn’t map to an item index path, like the space between cells.`

Comment: Could you just use a filler view, such as a `Color` view with 0.01 opacity? Throw that wherever you need to register the taps and it should work... even though there's probably a better way of doing it.

Comment: @CharlieReeder I don’t think so because List takes up all available space. But I’ll give it another try.